# Acessing Firebase from javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using Firebase in an iOS app, I am trying to do the following from javascript on a server related to the app, without really knowing if that is possible.

The javascript is calling this function, to write something on the Firebase DB:

```
function writeToFireBase()
{
  var config = {
    apiKey: "myKey",
    authDomain: "xyz-h123.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xyz-h123.firebaseio.com/",
    storageBucket: "gs://xyz-h123.appspot.com/"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  var database = firebase.database();
  database.ref().childByAutoId.set({"A":11, "B":44});
}
```

To start with my rules are set to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

But it does not work.

My question is: Is it supposed to work?
If YES, then what did I do wrong?

For rereference, I followed this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start
But since I am including the information I found in some existing context I am not so confident about the way I did it.

Comment: I suggest you always work with the console open. You would have seen something like *"cannot read property 'set' of null at ..."*

Comment: With the console open I wait and get a timeout, but I never see any message like you mention.

Answer (score 2):

The web SDK version of `childByAutoId` is [`push`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push)

```
database.ref().push().set({"A":11, "B":44})
```

Comment: That does not work either, there must something else wrong.

Comment: Not really, just waits and times out.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably resolve your problem.

```
function writeToFireBase()
{
  var config = {
    apiKey: "myKey",
    authDomain: "xyz-h123.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xyz-h123.firebaseio.com/",
    storageBucket: "gs://xyz-h123.appspot.com/"
  };

  // Initialize the app
  var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Use database reference from app
  var database = app.database();
  database.ref().push({"A":11, "B":44});
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of ** ?

Comment: That was just to highlight the difference, just initialize it in a variable and use database instance from that app

Comment: Also, based on whether you want to push or set to a specified key update the last statement.

Comment: how did you fix this issue ?